# How can get name from id stored with comma in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some table like below

```
with tba as(
    select 1 as t1id, 'n1' as name1 union all
    select 2 as t1id, 'n2'  union all
    select 3 as t1id, 'n3'  union all
    select 4 as t1id, 'n4'  
),
tbb as(
    select 1 as t2id, 'nb1' as texts, '1,2,' as t1id union all
    select 2 as t1id, 'nb2' as texts, '3,4,' union all
    select 3 as t1id, 'nb3' as texts, '' 
)
select t2.t2id, t2.t1id, t2.texts, t1.name1
from tbb t2 
left join tba t1 on ','+t2.t1id+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),t1.t1id)+',%'
```

But the result I want.

| t2id | t1id | texts | name1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2, | nb1 | n1,n2 |
| 2 | 3,4, | nb2 | n3,n4 |
| 3 | Null | nb3 | NULL |

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do not fix your design? That's the *real* problem here.

Comment: @Larnu: A db have alot of person using. So I can't

Comment: Fix the bad design. That's the real problem. Never mix up values like this

Comment: @HongVanVit `So I can't` you can't NOT fix this. This breaks the most fundamental database rule. As in if that's broken, everything is broken. There's no way to use indexes to speed up queries like this. The server will have to scan all rows every single time. Which means your database is already crashing even with a tiny amount of data

Comment: Then a lot of people are suffering a poor design choice, @HongVanVit . You'll make everyone's lives better if you fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not change your query much and added a few thing to get the expected results.  Generated row number to filter out the duplicate records and combine the current value with lead value to get your last column result.

```
 with tba as(
   select 1 as t1id, 'n1' as name1 union all
   select 2 as t1id, 'n2'  union all
   select 3 as t1id, 'n3'  union all
   select 4 as t1id, 'n4'  
  ),
 tbb as(
    select 1 as t2id, 'nb1' as texts, '1,2,' as t1id union all
    select 2 as t1id, 'nb2' as texts, '3,4,' union all
    select 3 as t1id, 'nb3' as texts, '' 
   )

Select 
 a.t2id
 ,a.t1id
 ,a.texts
 ,a.[name] as [name1]
 from
  (
     select t2.t2id, t2.t1id, t2.texts, t1.name1
, case when lead(t2.t2id ) over (partition by t2.t2id Order by t2.t2id) =  t2.t2id Then  name1 + ','+ lead(t1.name1 ) over (partition by t2.t2id Order by t2.t2id) 
else name1
end as [name],
row_number() over (partition by t2.t2id order by t2.t2id) as id
from tbb t2 
left join tba t1 on ','+t2.t1id+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),t1.t1id)+',%'

 ) as a 
 where a.id = 1
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @HongVanVit Let me know if you need any more support. Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out - performance will be abysmal because techniques like this can't use indexes - but in SQL databases with [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) and [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) support you can do the following:

```sql
with tba as (
  select * from (values
    (1, 'n1'),
    (2, 'n2'),
    (3, 'n3'),
    (4, 'n4')
  ) data (t1id, name1)
),
tbb as(
  select * from (values
    (1, 'nb1', '1,2'),
    (2, 'nb2', '3,4'),
    (3, 'nb3', '')
  ) data (t2id, texts, t1id)
)
select tbb.t2id, tbb.t1id, tbb.texts, joinified.name1
from tbb
outer apply (
  select string_agg(name1, ',') as name1
  from tba
  join (select value from string_split(tbb.t1id, ',')) splitified (value)
    on splitified.value = cast(t1id as nvarchar(10))
) joinified;
```

Which yields:

| t2id | t1id | texts | name1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2 | nb1 | n1,n2 |
| 2 | 3,4 | nb2 | n3,n4 |
| 3 | null | nb3 | null |

Answer (score 0):

You have to additionally group by `tbb` columns:

```
select t2.t2id, t2.t1id, t2.texts, string_agg(t1.name1, ',')
from tbb t2 
left join tba t1 on ','+t2.t1id+',' LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),t1.t1id)+',%'
group by t2.t2id, t2.t1id, t2.texts
```